# Mostrar um botão e ocultar outro

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Bom dia, estou tentando criar vários botões que mostrem outros botões.
Estou tentando fazer que ao clicar em um botão mostre o conteúdo e ao clicar em outro botão o conteúdo do anterior desapareça e o conteúdo do outro botão apareça.

```js
function minasgerais(el) {
        let display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
        if(display == "none")
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
    }
function Bahia(el) {
        let display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
        if(display == "none")
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
    }
```

```css
#minasButton{
    display:none;
}
#BahiaButton{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="minasgerais('minasButton')">Minas Gerais</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Bahia('BahiaButton')">Bahia</button>
<div id="minasButton">
TESTE1
</div>
<div id="BahiaButton">
TESTE2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa de criar uma função para cada estado, o fato de esconder e mostrar um determinado elemento na DOM não é inerente ao estado que o utilizador escolheu, é apenas uma reação ao uma ação do utilizador. Pense o seguinte, se no futuro adicionar outra feature que precisa reagir a escolha do estado, como você faria? Por exemplo, mostrar a bandeira do estado no header que é um componente com o seu próprio contexto.

Nesse caso não separando as responsabilidades, todos os componentes do sistema começam a ser fortemente acoplados, dificultando a manutenção e evolução. Se no futuro o header for trocado completamente e existir uma função que é fortemente acoplado ao header e ao mesmo tempo a outra parte do sistema, fica bem mais difícil fazer a troca do header.

Um bom exemplo para manter aplicação saudável seria implementar o padrão [Observer](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual_articles/observer-design-pattern-in-javascript) , mas isso depende do contexto e complexidade da aplicação, apenas deixei a referência para que saibas que existe essa possível solução.

Porém, deixo uma solução mais simples. Podemos separar as responsabilidades na mesma utilizando [custom events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent), ou seja, a responsabilidade de selecionar um estado não deve estar na mesma função que reage a essa escolha.

Para definir cada estado, utilizei o [ISO_3166-2:BR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:BR):

```html
<button type="button" onclick="selecionaEstado('br-mg')">Minas Gerais</button>
<button type="button" onclick="selecionaEstado('br-ba')">Bahia</button>
<div id="br-mg" class="wrapper">
    Escolheu o estado MG
</div>
<div id="br-ba" class="wrapper">
    Escolheu o estado BA
</div>
```

A função `selecionaEstado` é responsável por informar ao sistema que o utilizador selecionou o respectivo estado:

```js
function selecionaEstado(estado) {
    const event = new CustomEvent("alteraEstado", {
        detail: { estado }
    });

    document.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Qualquer componente do sistema agora está apto a escutar e reagir a mudança do estado:

```js
document.addEventListener("alteraEstado", (event) => {
    const estado = event.detail.estado;

    document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper').forEach(function(el) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    });
    document.getElementById(estado).style.display = 'block';
});
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
   display: none;
}
```

[Aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/myng0t7j/) podes encontrar o código a funcionar.

É importante salientar que o CustomEvent tem [limitações de compatibilidade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#browser_compatibility) com o Internet Explorer.

Comment: Muito obrigado vou dar uma estudada.

Comment: Eu queria colocar outros botões dentro destes para mostrar o conteudo mas quando coloco mais botoes e clico neles os outros somem

Comment: Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Consegui, porém não funciona no internet explorer

Comment: Sabe como posso fazer para que funcione no explorer?